# How can I use Tkinter with Python 3.11.3 that I built from source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I use `Tkinter` with Python 3.11.3 that I built from source?

I have another version of Python (3.10.6) that came with my distribution (Pop!_OS) and on that version I can successfully import tkinter.

But when I run Python 3.11.3 that I build from source I get the following messages:

```
>>> import tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
```

I used the following script builder to build Python 3.11.3 from source.

https://www.build-python-from-source.com/

If you have found a way to install `Tkinter` so that it can work with the version of Python 3.11.3 that you built from source, please reply with the details.

I have done a lot of searching to find a way to do this, but so far have not been successful.

Obviously `Tkinter` must be on my system, but, for some reason Python 3.11.3 can not "see" it.

Comment: You need to have had the Tk headers present at build time. (You'll also want to make sure you have SQLite headers, SSL headers, etc. if you want a complete standard library. [This list](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment) is a good starting point.)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply.  How does one have the Tk headers present at build time?  What has to be in the build script to accomplish this?

Comment: I've never used that script builder, not sure how it works. But with `pyenv`, you just need to install the system packages before compiling Python from source. I believe the Debian / Ubuntu instructions from the link I provided should work with Pop!_OS.

Comment: You need to install *development packages* of `tk` using the system package manager.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install required Tcl/Tk development packages like this.

```
$ sudo apt install tk-dev
```

Then the Python build system will enable and build the Tkinter extension. (You need to run the `configure` and `make` command again.)

Comment: The step that I had been missing was to invoke

sudo apt install tk-dev

After doing that, and running configure and make again

then the python 3.11.3 that I had built from source was able to
Import tkinter

So thanks for everyone’s replies.

Comment: It helped me while trying to install python 3.12.0 using pyenv